# Passing dynamic parameters into a function

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose i have a function called `ssh_connect` that takes a server SSH settings as parameters.Now i have multiple servers and i want to choose one of them randomly and input them as parameters into the function.Moreover if $result is empty when using one set of parameters , the other set must be used

`$result=ssh_connect($ip, $user, $pass, $port,$command)`

Suppose i have the following details

```
//Server 1 


$ip="123.456.78.901";
$user="root"
$pass="mypassishere"
$port = "22"

//Server 2
$ip="225.456.98.901"
$user="root"
$pass="mypassishere"
$port = "22"
```

I could use selection structures but that solution is heavily flawed as one server will always have priority over the others.It will be like if `$result` is empty with Server 1 details , move to server 2 , which is really not what i want.

I am thinking of array but i am not sure how it will be done since i need to select a set of details randomly and if one set fails try another one until there are no servers or $result has got a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued from @gwillie 's answer, here is an example:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array('host'=>'host1','user'=>'user1','pwd'=>'pwd1'),
    array('host'=>'host2','user'=>'user2','pwd'=>'pwd2'),
    array('host'=>'host3','user'=>'user3','pwd'=>'pwd3'),
    array('host'=>'host4','user'=>'user4','pwd'=>'pwd4'),
    array('host'=>'host5','user'=>'user5','pwd'=>'pwd5'),
);
$connect = false;
while (!$connect) {
    $srvIndex = array_rand($a);
    $host = $a[$srvIndex];
    $connect = my_connect_function($host); //Return true on success, false on error
}
```

Comment: I get the idea here but want i want to choose other servers in case one fails(excluding the one that failed ofc).You example show that it will just take any of them in case of a failure

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [aray_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), php site states

```
Picks one or more random entries out of an array,
and returns the key (or keys) of the random entries.
```

If settings fail, unset the key returned by `array_rand()`, keep looping till you connect, or fail

Comment: Yeah i though this as well but here there is a specific set of elements that would be needed for each server(since each server has unique ssh details) and i am not sure how its going to be.Could you elaborate more with an example